# How to set element attribute using phpunit-selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'd like to do something like:

```
// pseudocode
$this->byCssSelector('p')->setAttribute('attributename', 'attributevalue');
```

How to do that in [phpunit-selenium](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`execute()`](https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/blob/ed9fc2a0df26ad804703877b0538e825079283fa/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Session.php#L60) to execute javascript and set the attribute using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute):

```
$this->execute(array(
    'script' => "document.getElementById('my_id').setAttribute('name', 'value');", 
    'args' => array()
));
```

Comment: Note, the ->value() method still works for setting the value attribute. Getting was removed in selenium 2.43, but they left the underlying POST in the wire prototcol.